# Stream Webcam to HTML in Node: Not Allowed to Load Local Resource

Tags: node.js, webcam

I'm following this github repo: https://github.com/tiagobutzke/LiveWebcamWithHTML5

I clone it, follow all the instructions, start the server and open the HTML page. Then, I get the following error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: blob:null/f550115a-8588-4919-bc01-e96a3ac7c8a6
```

I guess it's because it's converting the stream to a local resource, which chrome can't use for security reasons because it's a browser. How do I run this without storing anything locally?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running the web page from file ."run it from http: not file".

Comment: I'm opening up the html page, which runs the javascript. Is that not correct?

Comment: No, Run it from some web server

Comment: I already mention in my question that I start the server according to the instruction using `node LiveWebcamWithHTML5/canvas/server/js/broadcast.js`

Comment: Second reason could be "For privacy and security reasons, Google decided to allow certain features only to "secure" origins, i.e. getUserMedia is only available on websites using HTTPS."

Comment: Check out this article for more details https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features